# Parallel_for instance of class member function

Tags: c++

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class testy {
    int *arr1, *arr2, *resu;
    int n;

    testy() {
        n = 100000000;
        arr1 = new int[n];
        arr2 = new int[n];
        resu = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr1[i] = i;
            arr2[i] = -i;
        }
    }

    void worker(int Idx) {
        resu[Idx] = arr1[Idx] + arr2[Idx];
    }
    void doTest() {
        parallel_for(0, n, worker);
    }

};
```

however I cant compile it since "testy::worker function call missing argument list"

the test worked fine while the worker wasn't a member of the class so I'm guessing I need to specify class instance here or something? How would I do that?

Comment: If it's [this `parallel_for` you're using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505035.aspx) then it's a non-standard function which you might have wanted to mention. As for your problem, it might be solved with e.g. [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: `parallel_for(0, n, [this](int i) {this->worker[i];});` should work.